# How to clear cache between Flutter tests?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm trying to write test involving a package that caches the method call result.

```
  /// Retrieves package information from the platform.
  /// The result is cached.
  static Future<PackageInfo> fromPlatform() async {

    // *** This is causing issue in tests ***
    if (_fromPlatform != null) {
      return _fromPlatform;
    }

    final Map<String, dynamic> map =
        await _kChannel.invokeMapMethod<String, dynamic>('getAll');
    _fromPlatform = PackageInfo(
      appName: map["appName"],
      packageName: map["packageName"],
      version: map["version"],
      buildNumber: map["buildNumber"],
    );
    return _fromPlatform;
  }
```

But all tests runs share the same instances of `PackageInfo` and therefore uses the cached result. How do I reset the cache after each test so each test uses its own instance of `PackageInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [the code from `package:package_info`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/package_info/lib/package_info.dart), there isn't a way to clear the cached value in `_fromPlatform`.  You can [file an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues) requesting that `PackageInfo` either provide a cache-control mechanism or easily allow the returned `PackageInfo` to be faked.

In the meantime, you always could implement your *own* function that bypasses `PackageInfo`'s cache and returns a fake `PackageInfo` in tests, and use that everywhere instead of calling `PackageInfo.fromPlatform` directly.